# How to create a lib with angular-cli

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

How do I build an angular lib home made thanks to angular-cli and then publish on npm repository?

I have to join other external lib inside and expose my module and some services in `index.ts` file.

What is the procedure to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning

Angular-cli release a version with a library generator.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v6.0.0-rc.2

> Library support! That was one of the most requested feature. You can generate a new library in your project by using ng generate library name.

Cheers